# parse.com not working after proguard

Tags: android, parse-platform, proguard, android-proguard

I'm using Parse.com features in my app, everything works great on debugging mode.
As soon as I generate a signed apk in release mode, I have a killing wait sometimes up to 10 seconds at the beginning of opening my app.
most probably it's because of Parse.com trying to initialize and contact its servers, which apparently is not successful.

And also, parse.com stops working I know so, since no data would be uploaded into my account.

There should be a problem with Proguard of course since the only difference between debug and release mode, is enabling proguard, in my case.

I have also triend to keep com.parse with following code in my proguard rules:

```
 #keep parse classes
-keepattributes Annotation,SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-dontwarn com.parse.**
-keep class com.parse.* { *; }
-keep class com.parse.** { *; }
```

any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:

I found out that a huge memory leak is happening at the Parse.initialize() after the Proguard ... still have no idea why though! 
Of course this memory leak is not present while proguard is off
[image]

Comment: My problem was about Apache `http-core` and `http-mime`, Do you have same libraries as mine? if so, then try to make them `-dontwarn` and `-keep class`.

Comment: @iSun perhaps mine should be same too, could you leave me exact line to add to proguad?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following if you have Apache `http-core` and `http-mime` along with `Parse` library:

```
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-keep class com.parse.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.parse.**
-dontwarn org.apache.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.**
```

Comment: did not help, unfortunately!
I found out that a huge memory leak is happening at the Parse.initialize() after the Proguard ... still have no idea why though!

Comment: @MuhammadNaderi Do you got any force close or ANR? if so, please edit your question and post your logcat.

Comment: Nope, only a white frozen screen for as long as 10 seconds, after that application works normally. even Parse.com works alright but the 10 second white screen is not acceptable, 
method proofing shows it's because of `com.parse.ParseCommandCache.maybeRunAllCommandsNow`
which is done in no time when proguard is off

Comment: @MuhammadNaderi Very odd situation, I think it's an ANR; it's better to contact with parse tech team.

Answer (score 0):

for com.fasterxml.jackson add below
    -keep class
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.
    ObjectMapper {
       public ;
       protected ;
    }
    -keep class
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.
    ObjectWriter {
        public ** writeValueAsString(**);
    }

Comment: got this errore: `proguard.ParseException: Expecting opening '{' at 'ObjectMapper'`

Comment: changing to this `-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper {
    public <methods>;
    protected <methods>;
}
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter {
    public ** writeValueAsString(**);
}
` passed proguard error, but the main problem still exists !

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem is some ANR in the Parse.com library, precisely when it tries to read its cash to sync previous unsynced data or something like this.

[image]

this happens due to the optimization, since with

```
-dontoptimize
```

parameter in proguard settings the problem is solved, although this is not a good idea, I think, and there should be a way to stop proguard from optimizing just this library.Although all I could find was this parameters :

```
# keep parse classes
#-dontwarn com.parse.**
-keep class com.parse.** { *; }
-keep interface com.parse.** { *; }

#-dontwarn org.apache.**
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-keep interface org.apache.** { *; }

#-dontwarn com.squareup.**
-keep class com.squareup.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.** { *; }

-keep class com.shygunsys.pocketcyber.techicalservices.parse.**



-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper {
    public <methods>;
    protected <methods>;
}
-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter {
    public ** writeValueAsString(**);
}
```

over the internet and SO to prevent Proguard from optimizing parse.com library and known libraries which parse uses, but as I said before no luck without the `-dontoptimize`
Any way, would be glad if I hear back from Parse.com developers, and/or Proguard guys to see whose bug is this